# Loop within loop JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm kind of new to all this JS, but I have a small project where I need to do some looping.

The output I'm given is an array with seven elements. Each of these elements contains another array with different elements. So basically what I need to do is to create an HTML block with data from the first element of the parent array, and inside that particular block I then need to loop over the array for that parent element to create x-amount of child blocks inside each parent block.

So what I am doing right now is the following:

```
            {Array.isArray(treatments) && treatments.map((treatment) => (
                <Fragment key={treatment.id}>                        
                    <h2>{treatment?.name}</h2>
                    <div className="row-header">
                        <div>Column 1</div>
                        <div>Column 2</div>
                        <div>Column 3</div>                    
                        <div>Column 4</div>
                        <div>Column 5</div>
                        <div>Column 6</div>
                        <div>Column 7</div>
                    </div>
                    {Array.isArray(treatment) && treatment.map((treatment_values) => (
                        <Fragment key={treatment_values.id}>
                            <div className="row">                    
                                <div>{treatment_values?.age}</div>
                                <div>{treatment_values?.name}</div>
                                <div>{treatment_values?.gender}</div>
                            </div>
                        </Fragment>
                    ))}        
                </Fragment>
            ))}
```

So coming from Python, this seems intuitive for me. I loop/map over the parent array, and then for each element of that array, i.e. `treatment` I loop over that element (or array) to get the elements from that. But that doesn't seem to work. It writes out the parent fragments, but these fragments doesn't contain anything.

Here is a console.log image of the what is actually given to me when the page loads:

[image]

So as you can see there are 7 elements in the parent array, which is loaded through the `treatments` mapping. Then inside each of these elements the first one contains an array with 6 items, the next 3 items as so on. I have no idea if it is because the child arrays are actually called the same as how I load the parent array (i.e. `treatments`), or I am just missing something basic.

Comment: The full structure of an item would be helpful but based on what you have currently it looks like your trying to map the parent object instead if it's ```treatments``` property in the second loop. Try ```Array.isArray(treatment.treatments) && treatment.treatments.map((treatment_values)``` in the second loop.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information. But apparently what you said worked. Easy pickens. Feel free to make an answer, and I will approve it :)

Comment: Saying more or less the same as GitGitBoom but yes the naming of the second treatment is def going to give you trouble. Think of it this way: Parent.treatments is still in scope when you hit Child.treatments. So you will have to call Child.treatments as some other name for the script not to flarp over it.

Comment: Thanks. I will tell my backends to maybe think about changing it :)

Comment: Perhaps just rename the outermost variable to something like `allTreatments`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `treatment` is an object so `Array.isArray(treatment)` is resolving to false every time.

To fix map the `treatment`'s `treatments` property instead.

```
 {Array.isArray(treatments) && treatments.map((treatment) => (
    <Fragment key={treatment.id}>                        
        <h2>{treatment?.name}</h2>
        <div className="row-header">
            <div>Column 1</div>
            <div>Column 2</div>
            <div>Column 3</div>                    
            <div>Column 4</div>
            <div>Column 5</div>
            <div>Column 6</div>
            <div>Column 7</div>
        </div>
        {Array.isArray(treatment.treatments) && treatment.treatments.map((treatment_values) => (
            <Fragment key={treatment_values.id}>
                <div className="row">                    
                    <div>{treatment_values?.age}</div>
                    <div>{treatment_values?.name}</div>
                    <div>{treatment_values?.gender}</div>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        ))}        
    </Fragment>
))}
```

You can also remove the `Fragment` in the second loop since you're already wrapping in a div, make sure to move the key down if you do so.